# Snaps stopped opening on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, snap

Whenever I open a snap, nothing happens. It used to work but now it doesn't. All of my software is up to date and I didn't change any settings nor did I add any repositories. Please help.

Update: My newly installed spotify and retroarch work. It isn't new for Spotify working but for retroarch it is.

Input of snap list :

```
Name                  Version                 Rev   Tracking  Developer     Notes
communitheme          0.1                     326   stable    didrocks      -
core                  16-2.32.8               4650  stable    canonical     core
discord               0.0.5                   66    stable    snapcrafters  -
minecraft             latest                  11    stable    snapcrafters  -
minecraft-nsg         2                       13    stable    nsg           -
retroarch             1.7.3                   118   stable    libretro      -
simplescreenrecorder  0.1                     1     stable    xiaoguo       -
spotify               1.0.80.474.gef6b503e-7  16    stable    spotify       -
```

Input of snap version:

```
snap    2.32.8+18.04
snapd   2.32.8+18.04
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-22-generic
```

Input of systemctl status snapd.service:

```
snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-06-02 11:36:07 EDT; 18min ago
 Main PID: 692 (snapd)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 2154)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
           └─692 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: 2018/06/02 11:46:09.257536 s
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "core": snap has no upd
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "minecraft": snap has n
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "communitheme": snap ha
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "spotify": snap has no 
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "retroarch": snap has n
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "minecraft-nsg": snap h
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "discord": snap has no 
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: snap "simplescreenrecorder":
Jun 02 11:46:09 adam-HP-Stream-Notebook snapd[692]: 2018/06/02 11:46:09.270581 a
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

Comment: Please add output of `snap version` , `snap list` and `systemctl status snapd.service` to the question.

Comment: Before I do, Spotify is the only snap that works.

Comment: Oh and btw, the newly installed spotify works and the retroarch now works but other than that, nothing else works

Comment: I added them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar issue, which seems to have started after a software update.

snap version:

```
snap    2.33.1+18.04ubuntu2
snapd   2.33.1+18.04ubuntu2
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-24-generic
```

snap list

```
Name                 Version                 Rev   Tracking  Developer           Notes
communitheme         0.1                     614   stable    didrocks        -
core                 16-2.33.1               4917  stable    canonical       core
hugo                 0.44                    2205  stable    hugo-authors    -
keepassxc            2.3.3                   38    stable    keepassxreboot  -
qownnotes            18.07.4                 1038  stable    pbek            -
spotify              1.0.80.474.gef6b503e-7  16    stable    spotify         -
ubuntu-mate-welcome  17.10.23-e4f4c4c        169   stable    flexiondotorg   classic
```

systemctl status snapd.service

```
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-07-21 10:23:47 ACST; 7h ago
 Main PID: 840 (snapd)
    Tasks: 25 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
           └─840 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: 2018/07/21 10:38:53.913415 storehelpers.g
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: snap "hugo": snap has no updates availabl
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: snap "ubuntu-mate-welcome": snap has no u
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: snap "spotify": snap has no updates avail
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: snap "qownnotes": snap has no updates ava
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: snap "core": snap has no updates availabl
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: snap "keepassxc": snap has no updates ava
Jul 21 10:38:53 dark-horse snapd[840]: 2018/07/21 10:38:53.915637 autorefresh.go
Jul 21 17:17:58 dark-horse snapd[840]: 2018/07/21 17:17:58.423179 api.go:1045: I
Jul 21 17:18:12 dark-horse snapd[840]: 2018/07/21 17:18:12.996129 api.go:1045: I
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

It seems to be a permissions issue. If I run an affected application from the command line:

```
steven@dark-horse:~$ qownnotes
/snap/qownnotes/1038/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /home/steven/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
Fatal: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0 ((null):0, (null))
Aborted (core dumped)
steven@dark-horse:~$

steven@dark-horse:~$ keepassxc
/snap/keepassxc/38/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /home/steven/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted
steven@dark-horse:~$ 

steven@dark-horse:~$ spotify
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(spotify:27512): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
steven@dark-horse:~$
```

ubuntu-mate-welcome (a classic snap) works as normal.

Reverting the affected snaps got them working again...

```
sudo snap revert qownnotes
```

...and the snaps continued to work after refreshing the snaps again.

```
sudo snap refresh qownnotes
```

Comment: This seemed to work for my issue with Syncthing, but not with Spotify. It tells me that Spotify can't revert. I guess I can try uninstalling it.

Comment: Uninstalling & re-installing the spotify snap seems to have resolved it.