# ubuntu studio 18.04 LTS snaps successfully create subdirectories but then report failure

Tags: snap

I have installed three apps (fre:ac, Inkscape and Okular) from the snap store via the built-in software app (v 3.28.1, presumably gnome-software) in Ubuntu Studio 18.04 LTS.  All appeared to install successfully, but none will launch.  When I try to start them, each app creates a subdirectory:
$HOME/snap/freac/1234
$HOME/snap/inkscape/7627
$HOME/snap/okular/98
but then complains "cannot create user data directory: ... : Permission denied"
Here are the outputs of "snap version":

```
snap    2.44.3
snapd   2.44.3
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-99-lowlatency
```

"Snap list":

```
Name                             Version                     Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core18                           20200427                    1754  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
freac                            1.1.1                       1234  latest/stable  enzo1982    -
gnome-3-28-1804                  3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498  116   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes                0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
inkscape                         1.0-6e3e5246a0-2020-05-07   7627  latest/stable  inkscape✓   -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0                      4     latest/stable  kde✓        -
okular                           20.04.0                     98    latest/stable  kde✓        -
snapd                            2.44.3                      7264  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

and "systemctl status snapd.service"

```
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-05-11 10:59:46 CEST; 1h 2min ago
 Main PID: 1040 (snapd)
    Tasks: 20 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
           └─1040 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Mai 11 10:59:45 DX5150 systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Mai 11 10:59:46 DX5150 snapd[1040]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Mai 11 10:59:46 DX5150 snapd[1040]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Mai 11 10:59:46 DX5150 snapd[1040]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.44.3 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/18.04 (amd64) linux/4.15.0-99-lo
Mai 11 10:59:46 DX5150 snapd[1040]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 1m0s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Mai 11 10:59:46 DX5150 systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Mai 11 11:13:17 DX5150 snapd[1040]: api.go:985: Installing snap "okular" revision unset
Mai 11 11:24:33 DX5150 snapd[1040]: api.go:985: Installing snap "inkscape" revision unset
```

I have read the thread "[Snaps stopped opening on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040972/snaps-stopped-opening-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)", but started a new thread because I have never (to my knowledge) had any working snaps on my system.

How can I get these apps to run, or at least figure out what's stopping them?

P.S. In my installation, $HOME does not point to a subdirectory of /home.  Could that be the cause of these problems?

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release (see https://ubuntustudio.org/2018/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-released/).  It was a standard release with 9 months of supported life (the base had 5 years yes, but not the Studio components).  You could extend that by adding PPA (https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/) but note Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was not a long-term-support release.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I had blithely assumed (as evidently did the poster of the thread referenced above) that this was an LTS version, based on the usual conventions.  Now I am not sure whether it is worth adding the backports repository as you suggest, since I plan to migrate to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 later this month.

Comment: You should always read release notes (eg. even main Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release notes highlight it too - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/18.04) and not make assumptions. Come upgrade time though read the new release notes prior to upgrade (eg. https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-lts-released/ for Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS which does suggest purging... likewise https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/UbuntuStudio)

Comment: @RB if I were to guess, I'd say it has to do with [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1643706) "feature". The path `/home` is hardcoded in the snap code, so your "awkward" choice broke it. If the respective snap permits it you can attempt to reinstall with `--classic`. But take a note of the output. A warning could be issued which tells you that `--classic` got ignored. Also, the output of `snap connections <pkgname>` could help.

Comment: Thanks, that is the likely explanation.  It seems weird, that snap would carefully create temporary directories under $HOME and then go look for them under /home!  Unfortunately, all three of the packages I wanted ignored the -classic option.

Comment: P.S. I guess I will just wait and see what happens with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.